# Use BeautifulSoup to extract sibling nodes between two nodes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got a document like this:

```
<p class="top">I don't want this</p>

<p>I want this</p>
<table>
   <!-- ... -->
</table>

<img ... />

<p> and all that stuff too</p>

<p class="end>But not this and nothing after it</p>
```

I want to extract everything between the p[class=top] and p[class=end] paragraphs.

Is there a nice way I can do this with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`node.nextSibling` attribute is your solution:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

nextNode = soup.find('p', {'class': 'top'})
while True:
    # process
    nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
    if getattr(nextNode, 'name', None)  == 'p' and nextNode.get('class', None) == 'end':
        break
```

This complicated condition is to be sure that you're accessing attributes of HTML tag and not string nodes.

Comment: I understand that this answer is old, but it has become obsolete. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#you-need-a-parser --- Also I find it unpythonic and dangerous even. If for some reason the website structure changes and there is no longer any tag with class `end`, your script will crash when next sibling becomes `None`