# BeautifulSoup get text without specific tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get text from a website. The HTML looks like this, simplified:

```
<div class="menu" style="clear:left;line-height:1.6em;padding-bottom:2em;">
  <strong>Monday</strong>
  <br/>
  Pasta
  <br/>
  Soup
  <br/>
  Fish
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <strong>Tuesday</strong>
  <br/>
  Sallad
  <br/>
  Hamburger
  <br/>
  Hot Dog
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <strong>SOUP OF THE WEEK: POTATO</strong>
</div>
```

I want to get all the dishes for each day. In my script, I call a function that returns the current day, lets call it get_current_day which returns "Monday" if todays day is Monday. How can I get a list containing ['Pasta', 'Soup', 'Fish'] then?

Comment: Get the siblings of the element `<strong>Monday</strong>` ? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507301/use-beautifulsoup-to-extract-sibling-nodes-between-two-nodes.

Comment: thanks! managed to solve it following that!